# Oracle APEX executing dynamic action on mouse movement or key press anywhere on page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there a way to execute a dynamic action by moving the mouse or pressing a key anywhere on the current page? Maybe with some jQuery selectors or something?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Tamas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else wondering about the solution:

Set the dynamic action Selection Type to "jQuery Selector", and set the jQuery Selector as "body", now when I press a key or move the mouse anywhere on the page the dynamic action fires.